# Using Linq, How can I properly append multiple Where clauses so that they appear in the appropriate order?

Tags: linq

The order I would like the end result to appear in is Exact Matches first given a input string, followed by other matches that are Contains for a given field.  I tried to approach this in a very rudimentary way as shown here in this example:

```
var raw = Model.SearchResults.Where(m =>  m.EffectiveDateTime != null).OrderBy(m => m.EffectiveDateTime).ToList();
    var exact = raw.Where(m => m.IssueNumber.ToLower() == Model.SearchText.ToLower());
    var contains = raw.Where(m => m.IssueNumber.ToLower().Contains(Model.SearchText.ToLower()));
    var list = exact.Union(contains);
```

This approach seems like it'd be a really bad way to do this.  In fact, the Union portion seems to effectively crash my application.  Is there an opposite to Intersection which would give me the remaining results outside the Exact matches that I could then append to a final list so that the order would be Exact Matches followed by StartsWith matches followed finally by Contains matches in that descending order?

Comment: What does "crash" mean exactly? Do you get an error message? What is it? Are you using EF or LINQ to SQL or is this LINQ to Objects? I believe you would need `m.IssueNumber.ToLower() != Model.SearchText.ToLower() && m.IssueNumber.ToLower().Contains(Model.SearchText.ToLower())` and then you would `Concat` after the exact matches.

Comment: Crash meant down to having to reboot for some reason...  IIS or Visual Studio just froze...  It's Linq to Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question, you can use a temporary expression to classify the match types, then order by the match type and other criteria, and it will translate to SQL as well:

```
var st = Model.SearchText.ToLower();
var list = Model.SearchResults.Where(m => m.EffectiveDateTime != null)
                              .Select(m => new {
                                  m,
                                  im = m.IssueNumber.ToLower()
                              })
                              .Select(mim => new {
                                  mim.m,
                                  Rank = mim.im == st ? 1 : mim.im.StartsWith(st) ? 2 : mim.im.Contains(st) ? 3 : 4
                              })
                              .Where(mr => mr.Rank < 4)
                              .OrderBy(mr => mr.Rank)
                              .ThenBy(mr => mr.m.EffectiveDateTime)
                              .Select(mr => mr.m)
                              .ToList();
```

I did the double `Select` to emulate `let` from fluent syntax, which I think is a bit clearer than lambda syntax in this case:

```
var lisx = (from m in Model.SearchResults
            where m.EffectiveDateTime != null
            let im = m.IssueNumber.ToLower()
            let Rank = im == st ? 1 : im.StartsWith(st) ? 2 : im.Contains(st) ? 3 : 4
            where Rank < 4
            orderby Rank, m.EffectiveDateTime
            select m)
           .ToList();
```

Also, if you do the whole query in the database, the `ToLower` is likely unnecessary, as the default for SQL is probably to be case-insensitive anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I went back to the drawing board and figured it out.  This is a little bit better for me and returns the results I needed.

```
        var list = Model.SearchResults
             .Where(e => e.A.ToLower().Contains(Model.SearchText.ToLower()))
             .GroupBy(d => new { d.A, d.B, d.C})
             .OrderBy(x => x.Key.A)
             .ThenBy(x => x.Key.B)
             .ThenBy(x => x.Key.C)
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 A= x.Key.A,
                 B= x.Key.B,
                 C= x.Key.C
             })
             .ToList();
```